# To add images to README.md on GitHub

Tags: github

To add images to a README.md file on GitHub, you can follow these steps:

Make sure the image you want to add is hosted online. If it isn't, you can upload it to a platform like Imgur or GitHub itself.

Copy the URL of the image you want to include.

In your README.md file, use the following markdown syntax to embed the image:

![alt text](image_url)
Replace alt text with a brief description of the image, and image_url with the URL of the image you copied earlier.

Save your changes to the README.md file and commit them to your repository.

When viewing your README.md file on GitHub, the image should be displayed.

Is that a correct way to it?

Answer (score 1):

Or like this

```
<img width="30px" src="./media/images/image_name.png" alt="image_name png" />
```

To use lazy loading for image

```
<img loading="lazy" width="30px" src="./media/images/image_name.png" alt="image_name png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

or like html

```
<img src='./a.jpg' width=60%>
```

for example
https://github.com/ZouJiu1/zhihu_spider_selenium/blob/master/README.md

Comment: To improve the accessibility of the page use alt text. <img src='./a.jpg' alt='image name' width=60%>