# Trying to get an image to show on my README.rm

Tags: image, github

I am trying to get an image on my github README.rm.

I have tried:

[How to add images to README.md on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494747/how-to-add-images-to-readme-md-on-github)

Which led me to the previous question here: [How to add screenshot to READMEs in github repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189356/how-to-add-screenshot-to-readmes-in-github-repository)

Those two did not help so I tried this: [To add images to README.md on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76627549/to-add-images-to-readme-md-on-github)

Looking at their README.rm on raw from shows that I did the same thing they did.

My file structure is this:

```
Project_02
    README.rm
    Scraper-Working.png
```

I have checked spelling and capitalization.

My code looks like this:

```
If you did everything correctly you should see this:

![Working Program](Scraper-Working.png)
![Working Program]("Scraper-Working.png")
![Working Program](/Scraper-Working.png)
![Working Program]("/Scraper-Working.png")

<img src="Scraper-Working.png" alt="Alt text" title="Optional title">
<img src="https://cats.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/cat-personality-e1705355000561.jpg" alt="Alt text" title="Optional title">
```

I tried the cats picture because I know it exists.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Within your code, if you click ctrl+ click on the image, does it show correctly?

Comment: Ctrl+click for the cat image works but my image is just a relative path so it doesn't even know it's a url.